# Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error). Using Apple Sign In With React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, apple-authentication

I'm building the Apple Sign In using React Native in an Expo project. I'd like to link the user to a firebase user however, I am getting the above error.

1. I have my Apple Sign In Key within the keys section on the Apple Developer Account.
2. I have added the `"expo-apple-authentication"` plugin to my `app.json` as per the below

   ```
   {
     ...
     "plugins": [
         [
           "expo-apple-authentication",
           [
             "@stripe/stripe-react-native",
             {
               "merchantIdentifier": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
               "enableGooglePay": false
             }
           ]
         ]
       ]
   }
   ```

### Here's the code

```
const createUserWithApple = async () => {
    try {
      const credential = await AppleAuthentication.signInAsync({
        requestedScopes: [
          AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.FULL_NAME,
          AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.EMAIL,
        ],
      });
      const { identityToken } = credential;
      if (identityToken) {
        console.log("ID TOKEN:", identityToken); // I AM GETTING TOKEN HERE YAY!
        const provider = new OAuthProvider("apple.com");
            provider.addScope("email");
            provider.addScope("name");
            const providerCredential = provider.credential({ identityToken });
            const result = await signInWithCredential(
              FIREBASE_AUTH,
              providerCredential
            );
            console.log("GOT RESULT:", result);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("CAUGHT ERROR:", error);
        }
      };
```

I'm not sure if I have my Service ID correct in the Firebase Console though. It appears to be my {MY_TEAM_ID.MY_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### SOLVED

Change:

```
const providerCredential = provider.credential({ identityToken });
```

To:

```
const providerCredential = provider.credential({ idToken: identityToken });
```